# Why I cannot change env.hosts from within a function?

Tags: python, fabric

I really need this to work somehow:

```
from fabric.api import *
from fabric.contrib import *

def test():
  global env
  env.user = 'vagrant'
  env.hosts = ['127.0.0.1', ]
  env.port = 2222
  env.key_filename = "/Users/sscarduzio/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key"
  run('ls /')
```

test case:

```
$ fab test
No hosts found. Please specify (single) host string for connection:
```

I can't figure out why it's ok to change the value of env.* outside a function and as soon as structure my code in functions (or classes) fabric ignores it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the answer was [right in the docs](http://fabric.readthedocs.org/en/1.8/usage/execution.html#execute). I didn't see it because Google always finds the old version of the docs, I don't know why.

The main issue is indeed with the propagation of the `env.hosts` (other env.* values seem to propagate normally.The solution to call a method with an arbitrary list of hosts was of invoking it using `execute(<someFunction>, hosts=<someHostList>)`.

For example:

```
from fabric.api import env, run, execute
def f1():
  someList = ['remoteHost1','remoteHost2']
  execute(f2, hosts=someList)

def f2():
  run('ls /')
```

To be run with the command: `$ fab f1`.

EDIT: updated version

Comment: I think you mean `execute(f2, hosts=someList)`

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for spotting it! :)

Comment: What is the "do" for in f1?  I am having the same problem as you (can't set env.hosts dynamically) but your method doesn't work for me. I get a syntax error with "do", and if I remove "do", I get prompted for the host list.

Comment: Interesting. It works from the command line, but not when called from another python script.

Comment: can you provide a minimal example?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `import *`, and don't use globals. There's no need for either.

```
from fabric.api import env, run

def test():
  env.user = 'vagrant'
  env.hosts = ['127.0.0.1', ]
  env.port = 2222
  env.key_filename = "/Users/sscarduzio/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key"
  run('ls /')
```

Comment: copy pasted above into a fresh ```fabfile.py```. Same result "No host found" :(

Comment: While you are completely right, this won't probabbly solve the problem, as it is semantically the same.

Answer (score 1):

With my Amazon machines I use:

```
from fabric.api import env, sudo

def set_env():
  env.host_string = "myuser@myhost"
  env.key_filename = "myfile.pem"

  # run commands
  sudo("ls /")
```

Comment: Thanks Alberto, that works indeed. The env.host_string works as one would expect. Apparently, there's a little more magic in the framework when you intend to use a list of hosts.

Comment: I have to move my script to develop changes in multiple servers so I will investigate more about the issue, and I will tell you more about it

Comment: Yeah, go for it. The solution is this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20530850/1094616

Answer (score 0):

you should try something like this:

```
def test():
  with settings(user='vagrant', host_string='localhost',...):
      run('ls /')
```

Comment: This is not working (here is what I tried):
  from fabric.api import env, run, settings
  def test():
    with settings(user='vagrant', hosts_string='localhost'):
        run('ls /')```

Answer (score 0):

According to what I found, `env` needs item access instead of attributes.

Thus, do

```
from fabric.api import env, run

def test():
    env['user'] = 'vagrant'
    env['hosts'] = ['127.0.0.1', ]
    env['port'] = 2222
    env['key_filename'] = "/Users/sscarduzio/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key"
    run('ls /')
```

I am not sure, however, if this information is right, and I haven't the ability to test it.

Comment: @sscarduzio Alas, no, as I don't have (experience with) fabric.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a fabric problem at all and although you can solve the problem this way you're better not to. SSH really does have much better tools for managing this issue, and for scaling up to more complex setups.

Firstly setup an alternate SSH config file, or add this to your `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host myvagrant
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  Port 2222
  User vagrant
  IdentityFile /Users/sscarduzio/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
```

At that point you should be able to ssh into myvagrant

```
$ ssh myvagrant
```

Or:

```
$ ssh -F .ssh_config myvagrant
```

Now your fabric code should read:

```
from fabric.api import *
env.use_ssh_config = True
#env.ssh_config_path = '.ssh_config'
@task
def f2():
    run('ls /')
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this does not fit more complex setups. Actually, your approach is just not good enough in the specific case. The SSH port Vagrant allocates for the current instance may vary. That's why in my real code I'm pulling the info programmatically via the local shell command: ```vagrant ssh-config``` and feeding it to Fabric at runtime.